# Adding search result from ArrayList more then one item

Tags: java, android, search, arraylist

I have a code for search items from my ArratList

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ItemClass temp : nomenclatureList) {
        if (temp.getNomenclatureName().contains(newText)) {
            tempList.add(temp.getNomenclatureName());
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<> ItemListGKI.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

But when executing this code, I see only one result value, not much. For example, I have 5 elements that have the word "patties". How can I bring all 5 items to the screen, not just the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just make all letters to lowercase like below,

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
boolean success = false;

ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
for (ItemClass temp : nomenclatureList){
    if (temp.getNomenclatureName().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
        tempList.add(temp.getNomenclatureName());
    }
}
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<> ItemListGKI.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        success = true;
return success;
}
```

Comment: Great to hear it works. Give your vote if it is useful. Thanks..:-) happie coding:-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is that you expect your enhanced for loop to execute completely, rather than returning on the first iteration.  This refactor suggests iterating separately to populate the list, then making a single assignment to create the `ArrayAdapter` and assign it to the `ListView`.

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ItemClass temp : nomenclatureList){
        if (temp.getNomenclatureName().contains(newText)) {
            tempList.add(temp.getNomenclatureName());
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<> ItemListGKI.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return true;
}
```

Note that I don't see why necessarily this method has to return a `boolean`.  It is changing the state of your view, and so might as well be `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

> Try to set adapter after for each loop, and you can also `return false` if adapter size is 0

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ItemClass temp : nomenclatureList){
        if(temp.getNomenclatureName().contains(newText)){
            tempList.add(temp.getNomenclatureName());
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<> ItemListGKI.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fill the tempList and finally set the adapter, so move this after the loop and delete the return statement in the loop:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<> ItemListGKI.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

so it will be:

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ItemClass temp : nomenclatureList){
        if(temp.getNomenclatureName().contains(newText)){
            tempList.add(temp.getNomenclatureName());
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<> ItemListGKI.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return true;
}
```